# Run code snippet while debugging in Intellij

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am debugging a java program and stopped at a breakpoint. There is a variable of list of 800 elements. Intellij only shows me the first 100. I wonder if I could execute some code at this point to inspect the elements? The "Evaluate Expression" functionality only allows me to run one line at a time.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of available elements can be set, see
[link](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/09/debugger-working-with-sub-ranges-for-arrays-and-lists/)

Just start Evaluate expression and you can change to code fragment mode

Comment: Thanks. Just found that as well. But I wonder in general you can run some code snippet to do things programmatically. Checking 800 elements manually might be fine. But if there is 8000 elements, it's gonna be hard.

Comment: you can also run code snippet in Intellij, not just evaluate expression. Search for code fragment mode

Comment: Just noticed that there is a code fragment mode. Thanks!